# Display gradle property in readme.md file

Tags: gradle, markdown

I have a gradle project with a gradle.properties file. One of the properties displays the current version of my project and I would like to include this proprerty in the project's README.md on github. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gradle [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task is capable of such functionality. Simply use its `expand` method to specify the values to insert. Of course you'll need to define a template somewhere in your project:

```
task copy(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/templates'
    into "$buildDir"
    include 'projectinfo.html.template'
    rename { file -> 'projectinfo.html' }
    expand(project: project, title: 'ProjectInfo', generated: new Date())
}
```

I took this example from a [post of Mr. Hakis Blog](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/10/gradle-goodness-parse-files-with.html).

This functionality is based on the Groovy [`SimpleTemplateEngine`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.5.4/html/gapi/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html). Of course you can simply use this class or any other templating engine to implement the required functionality in your build script on your own.

Answer (score 0):

@KrispyK,

I believe this would be possible. You could write a simple [serverless script using webtask](https://webtask.io/) (or similar service) that reads your gradle properties file and creates a custom status badge using a badge service like [shields.io](https://shields.io/#/). Finally, you would only need to add this badge to your markdown file.

**Please refer to [this webtask script](https://github.com/ClydeDz/cicd-docs/blob/master/.webtask/cicd-docs-uptime.js) that I created**. This calls an external API and uses the data returned by that API to [create a custom Shields badge](https://github.com/ClydeDz/cicd-docs/blob/cfcecf81e78bc9f2a9df9b534112edd3a845a9b2/.webtask/cicd-docs-uptime.js#L17). 
I've then [used this badge in my readme file](https://github.com/ClydeDz/cicd-docs/blob/master/README.md).

Hope this helps.